# Why doesn't my program go to game()?

Tags: python

My game gets caught in a loop and doesn't continue after the last `self.custom_input` in `def __init__(self):`. Why does it restart from the beginning instead of calling `game()`?

```
class game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Continue = None
        self.game = None
        self.score = score()
        while self.Continue == None:
            self.Continue = raw_input("Question")
        print "Good Luck...."
        while self.game not in ("no", "quit", "leave", "n"):
            self.rounds = self.custom_input("How many rounds would you like? ", self.games)
            game()


    def game(self):
        while self.score.rounds != self.rounds:
            self.score.rounds += 1
            self.user_choice = custom_input("question",self.plays)
            self.computer_choice = computer_choice()
            result = evaluate()
            if result == "win":
                print "statement"   %(self.user_choice.capitalize(), self.computer_choice)
                self.score.wins += 1
            elif result == "loss":
                print "statement" %(self.computer_choice.capitalize(), self.user_choice)
                self.score.losses += 1
            else:
                print "statement"        %(self.user_choice.capitalize())
                self.draws += 1
            self.score.rounds += 1
        finals()
```

Comment: You are defining `game` twice, with `self.game = None` and `def game(self)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've named the `game.game` function with the same name as the `game` class, as well as the `self.game` attribute, and the interpreter is assuming that you're trying to create a new instance of the `game` class. To fix this, try renaming the `game` function to `play_game`, and then do this:

```
self.play_game()
```

Comment: Sure thing! Was just commenting on the other answer.

Comment: I read your profile and saw your addicted to code review, so make sure you review this program once it's posted next week ;)

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes Sure thing! You can just @ notify me here with the link once you post it. :)

Comment: Here's the [program](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109813/rock-paper-scissors-w-scores-and-save-file) would appreciate your review.